# How to add animate to the alphabets inside a react carousal?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to do a carousal like in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/JustusFT/pen/ENLZGJ) using React Hooks.

My present result is in this Sandbox: [Click..!](https://codesandbox.io/s/newsld-ohhuz?file=/src/components/SlideCard.js)

The problems I'm facing are:

1. I don't know how to make that CSS animation effect of the letters coming and forming the text and scattering back as in the `CodePen` example.
2. I want to include the description part also which is in the `description={data.desc}`. Do I have to make the split again or any easy method to split both title and description together. I lag knowledge here.

My code is as below:

```
import React from "react";

export default function SlideCard(props) {
  const { id, idx, title } = props;

  function mainText() {
    return (
      <div style={{ border: "2px solid gold" }}>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
  //console.log(id);
  function scatter() {
    return (
      <div>
        {title.split("").map((item, index) => {
          const style = {
            position: "absolute",
            top: Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + "px",
            left: Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + "px",
            zIndex: "initial",
            color: "#AAA",
            overflow: "hidden",
            transition: "left 2s, top 2s, color 2s"
          };

          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <div className="scatter" style={style}>
                {item}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{idx === id && mainText()}</div>
      {idx !== id && scatter()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Some initial thoughts: I think you need to wrap each letter (or like half) in a span, then animate those letters

Comment: Actrually, I don't know how that split letters are coming and getting joined and forming a text.

Comment: No problem! Say your text is in an element with id `myEl`. Then you could do: `document.getElementById('myEl').innerHTML = '<span>'. + document.getElementById('myEl').innerText.split('').join('</span><span>') + '</span>';`

Comment: @Chris, I already have a split running to split the Text into letters. I have added a link, please have a look at the CodeSandbox link.  The problem is that i'm not able to animate the existing split letters to come and form the Text as in the first CodePen link.

Comment: just a hint, you'll get a better performance if you animate transition:translate, rather than top/left/bottom/right-properties.

Comment: He's maintaining two same copies of each page data. One with class `.position-data` and one with `.mutable`. He refers to `.position-data` copies to bring them back together. And `.position-data` class has `visibility: hidden;` .

Answer (score 3):

He's maintaining two same copies of each page data. One with class `.position-data` and one with `.mutable`. `.position-data` is hidden and only used for getting coordinates to bring back `.mutable` letters together. 
Here is the simplified version of the `CodePen` example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  assemble();
});

function scatter() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var randLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).width());
    var randTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).height());
    //randomly position .mutable elements
    $(".mutable > span:eq(" + i + ")").animate({
      left: randLeft,
      top: randTop,
      color: "#0005"
    }, 2000, "easeInBack");
  }
}

function assemble() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $(".mutable > span:eq(" + i + ")").animate({
      //get center position from .position data marked elements
      left: $(".position-data > span:eq(" + i + ")").offset().left + "px",
      top: $(".position-data > span:eq(" + i + ")").offset().top + "px",
      color: "#000"
    }, 2000, 'easeOutBounce');
  }
}
```

```css
span {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.position-data {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0.4;
  color: green;
}

.mutable span {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="position-data">
  <span>a</span>
  <span>b</span>
  <span>c</span>
</div>
<div class="mutable shadowed">
  <span>a</span>
  <span>b</span>
  <span>c</span>
</div>
<button onclick="scatter()">Scatter</button>
<button onclick="assemble()">Assemble</button>
```

> I want to position the actively displaying Text container to the centre of the carousal.

The actively displaying text container is marked with `.mutable` class which has following css:

```css
    .mutable {
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: inline-block;
    
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
```

So they all have full size of the document body. Using javascript function `arrangeCurrentPage()` in codepen they are set with coordinates such that they look centered.

> I don't know how to make that transition effect of the letters coming and forming the text and scattering back as in the CodePen example.

Refer to above simplified code. Use the buttons to see the effects separately. All letter elements are put in a div with class `.mutable`. All letters are `position: absolute;` so they are free to move anywhere.  In javascript function `scatter()` I am simply assigning `top` and `left` properties to random coordinates. With animation effect they scatter smoothly. In codepen he is achieving the animation effect using css transition `transition: left 2s, top 2s, color 2s;`

To bring them back simply us css selector nth-child `.position-data > span:eq(n)` to get corresponding coordinates of the character. Refer javascript function `assemble()`.

> I want to include the description part also which is in the description={data.desc}. Do I have to make the split again or any easy method to split both title and description together. I lag knowledge here.

As title and description will be displayed separately with separate presentation styles. Code will be cleaner if you keep split versions of them separately. You can create utility methods like `split(text)`, `scramble(array)`, `arrange(array)`and use it for both like `cramble(titleArray)`and `scramble(descArray)`.

---

If we use 'position:relative' on letters we don't have to maintain two copies of same data:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Document</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      assemble();
    });

    function randomX() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).width() * 0.7) - $(window).width() * 0.25;
    }

    function randomY() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).height() * 0.7) - $(window).height() * 0.25;
    }

    function scatter() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $(".mutable > span:eq(" + i + ")").animate({
          left: randomX(),
          top: randomY(),
          color: "#f118"
        }, 2000, "easeInBack");
      }
    }

    function assemble() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $(".mutable > span:eq(" + i + ")").animate({
          left: '0px',
          top: '0px',
          color: "#000"
        }, 2000, 'easeOutBounce');
      }
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    span {
      font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    .mutable {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    
    .mutable span {
      position: relative;  /* <--- */
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="mutable">
    <span>a</span>
    <span>b</span>
    <span>c</span>
  </div>
  <button onclick="scatter()">Scatter</button>
  <button onclick="assemble()">Assemble</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox demo you want to emulate is using an animation they call Alphabet Soup. After a quick google search, I found an npm package that can help you implement this in your react component: https://github.com/OrigenStudio/react-alphabet-soup.

Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: It's for the knowledge bro.. Moreover, my app will be independent of any dependencies.